# Deleting item from JTable & serialize them into file

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a program which have a jtable implemented, i used a array to store header & a bidimentional array of Object to store the data.

My JTable doesn't implement a VECTOR instead i use Simples Arrays.

```
 String[] headerColum = {"ID", "DESC", "DATE", "FIXEDDATE"};

      Object[][] data = {{"100414774", "harry", new Date(), dateFixed},{"122054", "Paul", new Date(), dateFixed},
      {"265015", "Matwe", new Date(), dateFixed}, {"12345", "unkonw Guy", new Date(), dateFixed}};


      TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, headerColum); 

      JTable table = new JTable(tableModel); //tableModel
      table.setModel(tableModel);
```

Aditional i had creatd a Jbutton which implement this method to delete a row:

```
JButton deleteBnt = new JButton("delete row");
      deleteBnt.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            if(table.getSelectedRow() != -1)
            {
                DefaultTableModel defaultableModel = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
                defaultableModel.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
                System.out.println("Delete complete");
            }

        }
    });
```

and it works fine, but when i try to save the Jtable's modelt into a file a error is thrown.
Save button:

```
JButton save = new JButton("save data");
      save.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
              try
                {
                    DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
                    ObjectOutputStream fileOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Harry/Desktop/clients.txt"));
                    fileOut.writeObject(model2);
                    fileOut.close();
                    System.out.println("writing Done");
                } catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });
```

error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.JTable$CellEditorRemover
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.event.EventListenerList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at FilteringJTable_add_deleteRow_save$4.actionPerformed(FilteringJTable_add_deleteRow_save.java:141)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can i serialize (Save it into a File without having this error?)?

Comment: Don't write the complete TableModel out to file. Instead extract the core data it contains and write that out.

Comment: Perhaps you want instead to store the Vector of Vectors obtained by calling `getDataVector()` on the model.

Comment: Agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels RE how to save the data. That being said, based upon the exception it seems you are serializing the JTable and not the model (`JTable.writeObject` is being called?)

Comment: @copeg: he's serializing the model as per his code above, but the model has lots of associated data that is not serializable, and may even call the method that you refer to above when you try to serialize it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Exactly i'm serializing the Model, but how can i serialize the data? if i'm not using vector

Comment: @Cohen: I already told you. And even if you're not using Vector, if you're using a DefaultTableModel **it** is using Vectors.

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels u helped me a lot. problem solved, thanks again :)